# Finding duplicate and non duplicate in Java

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I know this question has been answered on "how to find" many times, however I have a few additional questions. Here is the code I have

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    List<String> l1= new ArrayList<String>();

    l1.add("Apple");
    l1.add("Orange");
    l1.add("Apple");
    l1.add("Milk");

    //List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
    //HashSet is a good choice as it does not allow duplicates
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for( String e: l1){

        //if(!(l2).add(e)) -- did not work
        if(!(set).add(e)){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Question 1:The list did not work because List allows Duplicate while HashSet does not- is that correct assumption?

Question 2: What does this line mean: if(!(set).add(e))
In the for loop we are checking if String e is in the list l1 and then what does this line validates if(!(set).add(e))

This code will print apple as output as it is the duplicate value.

Question 3: How can i have it print non Duplicate values, just Orange and Milk but not Apple? I tried this approach but it still prints Apple.
List unique= new ArrayList(new HashSet(l1));

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: 1 is answered in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Set: "*A collection that contains no duplicate elements*". 2 is answered in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) of the add method: "*Returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element*"...

Comment: for Q 3, when you create a list by passing in a set, it will create a new list with all the elements of the set. So the list will have all unique elements, but it will have all the elements. Which is why apple is still being printed.

Comment: Q1: List also works fine imo. You only need to check for existence of the element to add. If it already exists, do not add it a second time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes that is correct. We often use sets to remove duplicates.

2) The `add` method of `HashSet` returns false when the item is already in the set. That's why it is used to check whether the item exists in the set.

3) To do this, you need to count up the number of occurrances of each item in the array, store them in a hash map, then print out those items that has a count of `1`. Or, you could just do this (which is a little dirty and is slower! However, this approach takes a little less space than using a hash map.)

```
List<String> l1= new ArrayList<>();

l1.add("Apple");
l1.add("Orange");
l1.add("Apple");
l1.add("Milk");

HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(l1);

for (String item : set) {
    if (l1.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(item)).count() == l1.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You're right.
2. Well... adding to the collection doesn't necessary need to return anything. Fortunately guys from the Sun or Oracle decided to return a message if the item was successfully added to the collection or not. This is indicated by `true/false` return value. `true` for a success.
3. You can extend your current code with the following logic: if element wasn't added successfully to the set, it means it was a duplicate so add it to another set `Set<> duplicates` and later remove all `duplicates` from the `Set`.

Comment: I will try the approach you have mentioned in 3, thanks.

Comment: @SheikhRahman if it was helpful - upvote. If solved your doubts - mark as accepted, please. If you need some clarification, just let me know

Comment: @xenteros For the third answer, if an element is present more than 2 times this logic will fail

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1:The list did not work because List allows Duplicate while HashSet does not- is that correct assumption?

That is correct.

> Question 2: What does this line mean: if(!(set).add(e)) In the for loop we are checking if String e is in the list l1 and then what does this line validates if(!(set).add(e))
>
> This code will print apple as output as it is the duplicate value.

`set.add(e)` attempts to add an element to the set, and it returns a `boolean` indicating whether it was added. Negating the result will cause new elements to be ignored and duplicates to be printed. Note that if an element is present 3 times it will be printed twice, and so on.

> Question 3: How can i have it print non Duplicate values, just Orange and Milk but not Apple? I tried this approach but it still prints Apple. `List<String> unique= new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(l1));`

There are a number of ways to approach it. This one doesn't have the best performance but it's pretty straightforward:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
    boolean hasDup = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < l1.size(); j++) {
        if (i != j && l1.get(i).equals(l1.get(j))) {
            hasDup = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasDup) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the /java8 power...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();

l1.add("Apple");
l1.add("Orange");
l1.add("Apple");
l1.add("Milk");

// remove duplicates
List<String> li = l1.parallelStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(li);

// map with duplicates frequency
Map<String, Long> countsList = l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fe -> fe, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(countsList);
// filter the map where only once 
List<String> l2 = countsList.entrySet().stream().filter(map -> map.getValue().longValue() == 1)
    .map(map -> map.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(l2);
}
```